# Removing special characters in field name using groovy

Tags: groovy, escaping

I have a field <Age (D.O.B)>.I want the result to be  i,e Age in brackets (unable to see my tag here)

I am using groovy.Please help.

I tried escaping the characters but unable to.

`def msgBodyModified21 = msgBodyOriginal.replaceAll('<Age'+\\s+'(D.O.B)>', '<Age>')`

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: def msgBodyModified21 = msgBodyOriginal.replaceAll('<Age'+\\s+'(D.O.B)>', '<Age>')

Comment: Can any one help me with the above code which is not working please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting on the regexp is wrong.  Use:

`"<Age (D.O.B)>".replaceAll(/<Age\s+\(D\.O\.B\)>/, "<Age>")`